# One of my migrations is not running with the php artisan command in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have several migrations I am running in Laravel 4.  I use the `php artisan migrate:rollback` and `php artisan migrate` commands to populate the tables.  Interestingly enough, one of my migrations has stopped working (cannot roll back).  All of the others are working fine.  I haven't changed anything to my knowledge.

The migration in question is named: `2013_06_19_050252_create_artists_table.php`

And it looks like so:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateArtistsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('artists', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('url_tag')->unique();
            $table->string('username');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('artists');
    }

}
```

I have no idea why this isn't working.  Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Where are you calling this? refer to [migration](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations) docs

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *isn't working*? Do you get an error?

Comment: No, it just won't show up on the list of migrations rolled back.

Comment: Or the list of migrations rolled up.  It just won't appear.  All other migrations are working fine.

Comment: Performing php composer.phar dump-autoload does not help the problem.  No errors were listed on autoload

Comment: Any other ideas?  This is driving me crazy..

Comment: Try with **php artisan migrate:refresh**?

Comment: I get the error: [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '  
  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: oh wait, didn't have mamp on, one moment...

Comment: weird, refresh worked.  But the other commands did not for the table.

Comment: Want to answer so I can give you the checkmark?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and did something similar to this to fix it. This is what worked for me.

1. Delete the tables and columns the migration is supposed to create if they are still there.
2. Rename the migration in the app/database/migrations file  by incrementing the last number in the migration file's name by one. Example: rename "2014_06_01_190448_create_users.php" to "2014_06_01_190449_create_users.php"
3. Run `composer dump-autoload` - this gets the old migration out of the system's memory
4. Rerun `php artisan migrate` in the command line

The file system basically thinks this is a new migration, so it gives it a "fresh start".

Comment: You have ended so much frustration for me. So many messy hacks and stupid workarounds. Thanks so much!! :)

Answer (score 4):

When you have problems with your migrations, sometimes

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

But if your migrations are really broken, and it happens sometimes, you may have to delete all your database tables and then run `php artisan migrate` again.

Comment: I have a similar issue where all my tables are migrated properly but somehow the migrations table in database is empty.. Deleted all the tables including the migration table and ran migrate command again but still same result.. not sure what is happening.. any clue?

Comment: I had the similar problem and thought the migration was not executed properly. Turns out that I had just hidden the table in MySQL. If you did, you can get it back by clicking the yellow light bulb at your table list.

Answer (score -1):

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Comment: Although, your answer is technically not wrong, it would help, if you could add some explanation.